# Locus of a point $P$ inside $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

> $P$ is a point inside $\triangle ABC$. $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are feet of perpendiculars from $P$ on $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ respectively. Find the locus of $P$ if $XY=XZ$ and $A \equiv (4,3)$, $B \equiv (4,7)$, $C \equiv (6,6).$

One way I can think of is by writing the equation of the lines $PX$, $PY$ and $PZ$ and find $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ in terms of the co-ordinates of $P$ by finding the intersection of these lines with the sides of the triangle. Then, using the distance formula, imposing the given condition.

But doing this is lengthy and  not feasible in a test. Is there a way to find the locus elegantly using geometry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since:

$$ XY^2 = PX^2+PY^2+2\, PX\, PY\cos C,\qquad XZ^2 = PX^2 + PZ^2 + 2\,PX\, PZ\cos B $$
the condition $XY=XZ$ implies:
$$ PY^2 - PZ^2 = 2 PX(PZ\cos B-PY\cos C).$$
Given that $[PX;PY;PZ]$ are the trilinear coordinates of $P$, the last condition implies that our locus is a conic. Two points obviously belong to such a conic: $A$ and the feet of the $A$-angle bisector. Other two points that belong to such a conic are the [isodynamic points](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsodynamicPoints.html) of $ABC$.

Comment: Interesting point being that $A$, the feet of the $A$-angle bisector and both isodynamic points of $ABC$ belong to the same circle of center $O_A$ being the intersection of the two bisectors (internal and external) of $A$-angle with $(BC)$ line and of radius$O_AA$. Worth having a look trying to prove that this circle might be the conic in question.